# How to set matching array values with conditions using computed property in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
 <div>
    <div v-for="box in boxes" :key="box.id">
      <BaseAccordian>
        <template v-slot:title>{{ box.name }}</template>
        <template v-slot:content>
          <div v-for="paint in paints" :key="paint.id" class="line">
            <div>
              <StatusComponent
                :box="box"
                :paint="paint"
                :matchingdata="matchingdata"
              />
              <!--only status like ok,not, medium to be printed on line accordingly -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </BaseAccordian>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How to set  matching array values  in Vuejs?

In my code, I have 3 arrays called, **boxes, paints, matchingdata**. By using those arrays, i want to perfome the functionality.

After the checkbox is clicked, At present i am showing some information related to **paints array**

So i need to set the matching array value condition here like.

Comment: If I understood your questions correctly you can filter out the paints list with lookup from the matchingdata collection something like: `v-if="matchingdata.some((m) => m.boxid == 
 ox.boxid && m.paintid == paint.paintid )`
              "
See here in action https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-elion-h08n8?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to update `matchingdata` inside your `StatusComponent`? This can be done by `emits`. There is a relevant example in the official vue documentation https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-component.

Answer (score 0):

you don't set matching array values with conditions using computed property in Vuejs, you can use method replace computed property

Comment: Now i achieved that functionality. Here it is codesandbox.io/s/musing-elion-h08n8?file=/src/components/… But only issue is, if i click on choc,chips, kat from the output.... I don't have any data to display there. So can i display some message there like no data